# Efficient input in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, user-input

Suppose I am writing an OCaml program and my input will be a *large* stream of integers separated by spaces i.e.

```
let string = input_line stdin;;
```

will return a string which looks like e.g. "2 4 34 765 5 ..." Now, the program itself will take a further two values i and j which specify a *small* subsequence of this input on which the main procedure will take place (let's say that the main procedure is the find the maximum of this sublist). In other words, the whole stream will be inputted into the program but the program will only end up acting on a small subset of the input.

My question is: what is the best way to translate the relevant part of the input stream into something usable i.e. a string of ints? One option would be to convert the whole input string into a list of ints using

```
let list = List.map int_of_string(Str.split (Str.regexp_string " ") string;;
```

and then once the bounds i and j have been entered one easily locates the relevant sublist and its maximum. The problem is that the initial pre-processing of the large stream is immensely time-consuming.

Is there an efficient way of locating the small sublist directly from the large stream i.e. processing the input along with the main procedure?

Comment: I don't see how this problem is anything specific to OCaml: incremental lexing is doable in OCaml just like it is in many languages.

Comment: It's specific to OCaml in as much as I don't know how to do it in OCaml. I don't dispute that it's possible.

Comment: I was with you until you said "i.e. processing the input in parallel". Are you specifically looking for a multi-threaded solution?

Comment: No, sorry, I just meant it metaphorically. Bad choice of words - changed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the `Scanf` module family of functions. For instance, `Scanf.fscanf` let you read tokens from a channel according to a string format (which is a special type in OCaml).

Your program can be decomposed in two functions:

- one which skip a number `i` of tokens from the input channel,
- one which extract the maximum integer out of a number `j` from a channel

Let's write these:

```
let rec skip_tokens c i =
  match i with
    | i when i > 0 -> Scanf.fscanf c "%s " (fun _ -> skip_tokens c @@ pred i)
    | _ -> ()


let rec get_max c j m =
  match j with
    | j when j > 0 -> Scanf.fscanf c "%d " (fun x -> max m x |> get_max c (pred j))
    | _ -> m
```

Note the space after the token format indicator in the string which tells the scanner to also swallow all the spaces and carriage returns in between tokens.

All you need to do now is to combine them. Here's a small program you can run from the CLI which takes the `i` and `j` parameters, expects a stream of tokens, and print out the maximum value as wanted:

```
let _ =
  let i = int_of_string Sys.argv.(1)
  and j = int_of_string Sys.argv.(2) in
  skip_tokens stdin (pred i);
  get_max stdin j min_int |> print_int;
  print_newline ()
```

You could probably write more flexible combinators by extracting the recursive part out. I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 9):

OCaml's standard library is rather small. It provides necessary and sufficient set of orthogonal features, as should do any good standard library. But, usually, this is not enough for a casual user. That's why there exist libraries, that do the stuff, that is rather common.

I would like to mention two the most prominent libraries: Jane Street's Core library and Batteries included (aka Core and Batteries).

Both libraries provides a bunch of high-level I/O functions, but there exists a little problem. It is not possible or even reasonable to try to address any use case in a library. Otherwise the library's interface wont be terse and comprehensible. And your case is non-standard. There is a convention, a tacit agreement between data engineers, to represent a set of things with a set of lines in a file. And to represent one "thing" (or a feature) with a line. So, if you have a dataset where each element is a scalar, you should represent it as a sequence of scalars separated by a newline. Several elements on a single line is only for multidimensional features.

So, with a proper representation, your problem can be solve as simple as (with Core):

```
open Core.Std

let () =
  let filename = "data" in
  let max_number =
    let open In_channel in
    with_file filename
      ~f:(fold_lines ~init:0
            ~f:(fun m s -> Int.(max m @@ of_string s))) in
  printf "Max number is %s is %d\n" filename max_number
```

You can compile and run this program with `corebuild test.byte --` assuming that code is in a file name `test.byte` and core library is installed (with `opam install core` if you're using `opam`).

Also, there exists an excellent library `Lwt`, that provides a monadic high-level interface to the I/O. With this library, you can parse a set of scalars in a following way:

```
open Lwt

let program =
  let filename = "data" in
  let lines = Lwt_io.lines_of_file filename in
  Lwt_stream.fold (fun s m -> max m @@ int_of_string s) lines 0 >>=
  Lwt_io.printf "Max number is %s is %d\n" filename

let () = Lwt_main.run program
```

This program can be compiled and run with `ocamlbuild -package lwt.unix test.byte --`, if `lwt` library is installed on your system (`opam install lwt`).

So, that is not to say, that your problem cannot be solved (or is hard to be solved) in OCaml, it is just to mention, that you should start with a proper representation. But, suppose, you do not own the representation, and cannot change it. Let's look, how this can be solved efficiently with OCaml. As previous examples represent, in general your problem can be described as a channel folding, i.e. an consequential application of a function `f` to each value in a file. So, we can define a function fold_channel, that will read an integer value from a channel and apply a function to it and the previously read value. Of course, this function can be further abstracted, by lifting the format argument, but for the demonstration purpose, I suppose, this will be enough.

```
let rec fold_channel f init ic =
  try  Scanf.fscanf ic "%u " (fun s -> fold_channel f (f s init) ic)
  with End_of_file -> init

let () =
  let max_value = open_in "atad" |> fold_channel max 0 in
  Printf.printf "max value is %u\n" max_value
```

Although, I should note that this implementation is not for a heavy duty work. It is even not tail-recursive. If you need really efficient lexer, you can use ocaml's lexer generator, for example.

## Update 1

Since there is a word "efficient" in the title, and everybody likes benchmarks, I've decided to compare this three implementations. Of course, since pure OCaml implementation is not tail-recursive it is not comparable to others. You may wonder, why it is not tail-recursive, as all calls to `fold_channel` is in a tail position. The problem is with exception handler - on each call to the fold channel, we need to remember the `init` value, since we're going to return it. This is a common issue with recursion and exceptions, you may google it for more examples and explanations.

So, at first we need to fix the third implementation. We will use a common trick with option value.

```
let id x = x
let read_int ic =
  try Some (Scanf.fscanf ic "%u " id) with End_of_file -> None

let rec fold_channel f init ic =
  match read_int ic with
  | Some s -> fold_channel f (f s init) ic
  | None   -> init

let () =
  let max_value = open_in "atad" |> fold_channel max 0 in
  Printf.printf "max value is %u\n" max_value
```

So, with a new tail-recursive implementation, let's try them all on a big-data. 100_000_000 numbers is a big data for my 7 years old laptop. I've also added a C implementations as a baseline, and an OCaml clone of the C implementation:

```
let () =
  let m = ref 0 in
  try
    let ic = open_in "atad" in
    while true do
      let n = Scanf.fscanf ic "%d " (fun x -> x) in
      m := max n !m;
    done
  with End_of_file ->
    Printf.printf "max value is %u\n" !m;
    close_in ic
```

## Update 2

Yet another implementation, that uses `ocamllex`. It consists of two files, a lexer specification `lex_int.mll`

```
{}
let digit = ['0'-'9']
let space = [' ' '\t' '\n']*

rule next = parse
| eof {None}
| space {next lexbuf}
| digit+ as n {Some (int_of_string n)}

{}
```

And the implementation:

```
let rec fold_channel f init buf =
  match Lex_int.next buf with
  | Some s -> fold_channel f (f s init) buf
  | None   -> init

let () =
  let max_value = open_in "atad" |>
                  Lexing.from_channel |>
                  fold_channel max 0 in
  Printf.printf "max value is %u\n" max_value
```

And here are the results:

```
implementation   time  ratio rate (MB/s)
plain C          22 s  1.0   12.5
ocamllex         33 s  1.5    8.4
Core             62 s  2.8    4.5
C-like OCaml     83 s  3.7    3.3
fold_channel     84 s  3.8    3.3
Lwt             143 s  6.5    1.9
```

P.S. You can see, that in this particular case Lwt is an outlier. This doesn't mean that Lwt is slow, it is just not its granularity. And I would like to assure you, that to my experience Lwt is a well suited tool for a HPC. For example, in one of my programs it processes a `30 MB/s` network stream in a real-time.

## Update 3

By the way, I've tried to address the problem in an abstract way, and I didn't provide a solution for your particular example (with `j` and `k`). Since, folding is a generalization of the iteration, it can be easily solved by extending the state (parameter `init`) to hold a counter and check whether it is contained in a range, that was specified by a user. But, this leads to an interesting consequence: what to do, when you have outran the range? Of course, you can continue to the end, just ignoring the output. Or you can non-locally exit from a function with an exception, something like `raise (Done m)`. Core library provides such facility with a `with_return` function, that allows you to break out of your computation at any point.

```
open Core.Std

let () =
  let filename = "data" in
  let b1,b2 = Int.(of_string Sys.argv.(1), of_string Sys.argv.(2)) in
  let range = Interval.Int.create b1 b2 in
  let _,max_number =
    let open In_channel in
    with_return begin fun call ->
      with_file filename
        ~f:(fold_lines ~init:(0,0)
              ~f:(fun (i,m) s ->
                  match Interval.Int.compare_value range i with
                  | `Below -> i+1,m
                  | `Within -> i+1, Int.(max m @@ of_string s)
                  | `Above -> call.return (i,m)
                  | `Interval_is_empty -> failwith "empty interval"))
    end in
  printf "Max number is %s is %d\n" filename max_number
```