# Split a string containing integers and spaces in OCaml

Tags: string, ocaml, split

Well, I have to read the input from a file, containing integers using OCaml. I have managed to read the whole file, but I get as a result a list containing strings of numbers and spaces.

For example:ret=["10 12 23";"43 09 87"] and so forth. I want to break every single string and save it on arrays(or lists) of integers. How can I do that? I've already checked the `Str.split` method but haven't made an further progress with that.

Comment: Re: "I've already checked the Str.split method but haven't made an further progress with that": What problems did you run into? Would you care to post the problematic code?

Comment: It depends on the format of your file. If you separate input with newlines it is trivial. Otherwise ... it is also trivial. Moreover, there're plenty of questions about input in ocaml. E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715724/efficient-input-in-ocaml/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    let s = "10 20 30 40 50 60" in
    let list_of_ints = List.map int_of_string (Str.split (Str.regexp " ") s)
```

This can obviously be made to accommodate a list of strings, etc.

Cheers,
Scott