# Reading numbers separated by spaces in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

What is the easiest way to read a bunch of integers from stdin separated by spaces? In this case I know how many there are, although the unknown case corresponding to the while(std::cin >> n) { a.push_back(n); } in C++ would be nice to know too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient input in OCaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715724/efficient-input-in-ocaml)

Answer (score 3):

You can give a try to the `Scanf` module. See its documentation [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html).

```
let get_ints queue =
 let aux () =
  Scanf.scanf "%d " (fun n -> Queue.push n queue); aux ()
 in
 try aux () with _ -> ()
```

Other standard way allow you to do it, you may want to take a look at [ocamllex](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lexyacc.html), [Str](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libstr.html) or [Genlex](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Genlex.html). Of course, there are other lexing/parsing libraries in OCaml but it would be quite a debate as to which one's the best.

Comment: yep, I've made some comparison about them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23719402/2625442