# Read a large file into string lines OCaml

Tags: ocaml, filereader

I am basically trying to read a large file (around 10G) into a list of lines. The file contains a sequence of integer, something like this:

```
0x123456
0x123123
0x123123
.....
```

I used the method below to read files by default for my codebase, but it turns out to be quit slow (~12 minutes) at this scenario

```
let lines_from_file (filename : string) : string list =                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    let lines = ref [] in                                                                                                                                                                               
 let chan = open_in filename in                                                                                                                                                                      
  try                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      while true; do                                                                                                                                                                                    
       lines := input_line chan :: !lines                                                                                                                                                              
     done; []                                                                                                                                                                                          
  with End_of_file ->                                                                                                                                                                                 
     close_in chan;                                                                                                                                                                                    
     List.rev !lines;;
```

I guess I need to read the file into memory, and then split them into lines (I am using a 128G server, so it should be fine for the memory space). But I still didn't understand whether `OCaml` provides such facility after searching the documents [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html).

So here is my question:

1. Given my situation, how to read files into string list in a fast way?
2. How about using `stream`? But I need to adjust related application code, then that could cause some time.

Comment: Why not print the lines into a new file instead? In reversed order, one line at a time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you should consider whether you really need to have all the information at once in your memory. Maybe it is better to process file line-by-line?

If you really want to have it all at once in memory, then you can use `Bigarray`'s [`map_file`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bigarray.Genarray.html#VALmap_file) function to map a file as an array of characters. And then do something with it.

Also, as I see, this file contains numbers. Maybe it is better to allocate the array (or even better a bigarray) and the process each line in order and store integers in the (big)array.

Comment: What is the situation with streaming in ocaml? Is the Stdlib's stream considered deprecated?

Comment: Yes it is on the edge. It actually was deprecated at the first release of OCaml, since it is an atavism of Caml Light. Otherwise, streaming is ok. You can use `Lwt_stream`, Async's pipes, Core's `Sequence` or batteries's `enum` to create a sequences or streams of characters/strings. But this all are just less general version of `In_channel.fold_lines` of Core library.

Comment: if its basically deprecated then why isn't it just removed from the stdlib.

Comment: Deprecation of Stream is [proposed](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6711).

Comment: Hi @ivg, may I ask what's your recommendation about "processing file line-by-line"? Using the `stream`?

Comment: If I were you, I would use `In_channel.fold_lines` or `In_channel.iter_lines` from `Core_kernel` library. If you don't want to use this library, then you basically can reimplement this function yourself. Or you just "do the work" inside your `while` loop, instead of accumulating strings in a list, for later processing. 
Also you may find this answer useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715724/efficient-input-in-ocaml/23719402#23719402

Comment: @ivg. Thank you! It is very helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

I often use the two following function to read the lines of a file. Note that the function `lines_from_files` is tail-recursive.

```
let read_line i = try Some (input_line i) with End_of_file -> None 

let lines_from_files filename = 
  let rec lines_from_files_aux i acc = match (read_line i) with 
    | None -> List.rev acc
    | Some s -> lines_from_files_aux i (s :: acc) in 
  lines_from_files_aux (open_in filename) [] 

let () = 
  lines_from_files "foo"
  |> List.iter (Printf.printf "lines = %s\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
let rec ints_from_file fdesc =
  try
    let l = input_line fdesc in
    let l' = int_of_string l in
    l' :: ints_from_file fdesc
  with | _ -> []
```

This solution converts the strings to integers as they're read in (which should be a bit more memory efficient, and I assume this was going to be done to them eventually.

Also, because it is recursive, the file must be opened outside of the function call.

Comment: That function is not tail-recursive, hence on a big file it will produce a stack overflow. Using an accumulator then ending with a `List.rev` would be a lot more advisable.

Comment: And even with accumulator the stack will still grow linear to the size of the file, due to a `try/with` section. @alifirat's solution is quite idiomatic.